# Python Align Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-alignment

i have following code:

```
index = 0
        for i in cryptos:
            print((cryptos[index]+ " - " + json.loads(json.dumps(response.json()))["data"][cryptos[index]]["name"]) + "         " + (str(json.loads(json.dumps(response.json()))["data"][cryptos[index]]["quote"][Convert]["price"])) + Currency_Symbol).exp
            index += 1
```

And the output is like that:

```
BTC - Bitcoin         59768.344187241666CHF
ETH - Ethereum         1859.0445209742907CHF
XMR - Monero         232.07519121223555CHF
LTC - Litecoin         216.55190970755382CHF
```

But i want the output to be:

```
BTC - Bitcoin         59768.344187241666CHF
ETH - Ethereum        1859.0445209742907CHF
XMR - Monero          232.07519121223555CHF
LTC - Litecoin        216.55190970755382CHF
```

I hope this was understandable enough and sorry for the really long line, its json ¯_(ツ)_/¯
i searched around on the internet but couldn't find a proper solution

FYI as the line is pretty long, the part **after** the `+ "         " +` is the price :D

Thx for the help in advance

Comment: For the very loooong line, you could use additional variables, like `name` and `price`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string `.ljust` or `.rjust` methods - [see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust)
The syntax is `"string".ljust(width, [optional character to fill defaults to space])`. This width will include the original string

Example -

```py
print((cryptos[index]+ " - ",
json.loads(json.dumps(response.json()))["data"][cryptos[index]]["name"]).ljust(20), 
(str(json.loads(json.dumps(response.json()))["data"][cryptos[index]]["quote"][Convert]["price"])) + Currency_Symbol).exp
```

In case i added it in the wrong place in that *long* line of code, A simpler example - `print('a'.ljust(5)+'b'.ljust(10)+'c')` would output

`a    b         c` - that's 4 spaces after the 'a' and 9 after the 'b'

Answer (score 0):

```
index = 0
spacing = 16
    for i in cryptos:
        space = " " * (spacing - len(i))
        print((cryptos[index]+ " - " + json.loads(json.dumps(response.json()))["data"][cryptos[index]]["name"]) + spacing + (str(json.loads(json.dumps(response.json()))["data"][cryptos[index]]["quote"][Convert]["price"])) + Currency_Symbol).exp
        index += 1
```

By increasing the spacing variable in the beginning, you can control how much gap you want between the two text.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're casting the json data to string, you can use the rjust and ljust methods of string to adjust the text.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to have a fixed width for name:

```py
print(name.ljust(20) + price)
```